# sending request from client to Android Web Server using Paw Server (Vice versa)

Tags: android, webserver, pawserver, paw

I configured paw server and basically can send request however dont find how to handle incoming requests from client on the serverside. Can anyone give any information how to do that?

EDIT: I can send request with GET action saying something at url like ihttp://192.168.12.103:7575/?testparametre=mustafa%20guven

and I can get it in index.html like below

```
gelenParametre = <bsh>$$.print(parameters.get("testparametre"));</bsh>
```

But what I want to do is getting the request in Activity Lifecycle. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a xhtml page:

_http://192.168.12.103:7575/**test.xhtml**?testparametre=mustafa%20guven

The code inside the *test.xhtml* file should look like this:

```
<bsh>
   gelenParametre = parameters.get("testparametre");
   print(gelenParametre);
</bsh>
```

Comment: I want to get it in activity not in an xhtml file.